# how to merge LSTM layers ? (layers, not sequencial() vars )

Tags: tensorflow, merge, keras, layer, lstm

I have this code :

```
    lstm1=LSTM(40,
        input_shape=(5,5),
        dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=False)


    lstm2=LSTM(40,
        input_shape=(5, 5),
        dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=False)

    merged = merge([lstm1, lstm2], mode='concat',concat_axis=1)
```

But I get this error :

```
merged = merge([lstm1, lstm2], mode='concat',concat_axis=1)
File "/home/rjpg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 470, in merge
return merge_layer(inputs)
File "/home/rjpg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 549, in __call__
input_shapes.append(K.int_shape(x_elem))
File "/home/rjpg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 451, in int_shape
shape = x.get_shape()
AttributeError: 'LSTM' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

How can I do it not using Sequencial() (using merge instead of Merge) ?

The goal is to feed this merge layer with the output of a maxpool layer that has an output dimension like :

```
    max_pooling2d (MaxPooling) (None, 2, 5, 5)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code lstm1 and lstm2 are layers not an output

so merge not works an gives  "'LSTM' object has no attribute 'get_shape'" error

First design code like this

```
inp = Input(...)
lstm1 = LSTM(...)(inp)
lstm2 = LSTM(...)(inp)
merged = merge([lstm1, lstm2], ...)
```

Comment: thank you. Ok I will try ... but I am not seeing yet how to define the inp1 for the image1 genereted by filter1 of the previous convnet and inp2 for the second filter image genereted but the same previous convnet (or max_pooling2d...).
In another works 
The previous layer output shape is (none, 2,5,5) I want [0][5][5] to enter lstm1 and [1][5][5] to enter lstm2.  The ideia is to have two lstm competing with input genereted by two filter from convnet (?)

Comment: "The ideia is to have two lstm competing with input genereted by two filter from convnet (?)"
ask ask as an another question